# Jquery Date picker Dynamic minDate -issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have a date picker jquery function

```
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  minDate: sprint_select(),
  maxDate: $( '#d_id' ).val(),
  onSelect: function (selected) {
    var dt = new Date(selected);
    $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
  }
});
```

Here i set  `minDate: sprint_select()`, calling function `sprint_select`.So

```
function sprint_select(){
  var r_id=$('#r_id').val();
  var dataString = { r_id: r_id}

  $.ajax({
    url: "/manage/scrum/getsprintprd",
    method: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    //                   dataType: "json",
    //cache: false,
    success: function (data)
    {
      //var values= $.trim(data).split("-");
      var values1 = '2018-11-09'.split("-"); 
      var parsed_date = new Date(values[0], values[1]-1, values[2]);
      return parsed_date;
    }
  });
}
```

here i return parsed_date successful.but no change in calendar min date.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have different things that go wrong here, i suggest you take a look to [this topic about how to return value from async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (an ajax call is async). So, in simple, your `sprint_select()` hasn't answered yet when datepicker is created, and actually it doesn't answer because the `return` in succes function returns for `success` and not for `sprint_select`.

Comment: Add your `datepicker` creation in ajax `success handler`

Comment: You could set value of `minDate` within `success` callback of the AJAX request.

Comment: @Alexander thanks i got it

Answer (score 0):

Try Calling Your datepicker function on sprint_select() success:
(because Getting date from api may take time. before that your datepicker function is getting completed.)

```
    function sprint_select(){
      var r_id=$('#r_id').val();
      var dataString = { r_id: r_id}

      $.ajax({
        url: "/manage/scrum/getsprintprd",
        method: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        //                   dataType: "json",
        //cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          //var values= $.trim(data).split("-");
          var values1 = '2018-11-09'.split("-"); 
          var parsed_date = new Date(values[0], values[1]-1, values[2]);

           $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
           beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
           numberOfMonths: 1,
           minDate: parsed_date ,
           maxDate: $( '#d_id' ).val(),
           onSelect: function (selected) {
           var dt = new Date(selected);
           $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
         }
       });

    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

maxDate like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="d_id" name="d_id" value="01-28-2019">
```

script

```
var max = new Date($( '#d_id' ).val());
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: sprint_select(),
    maxDate: max,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
       var dt = new Date(selected);
       $("#to_date").datepicker({
          minDate: dt,
       });
    }
});
```

Check Ajax return value it should be in mm/dd/yyyy format

```
function sprint_select(){
    var parsed_date = new Date('01-02-2019');
    return parsed_date; 
}
```